# How to pull data from ADLS to Azure Data Explorer(Kusto) with selected columns from source table using azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-explorer, azure-data-lake-gen2, kusto-explorer

how to pull selected columns from ADLS table to azure data explorer(kusto), please give some screen shots for creating linked & Data sets for easy to understand.

Comment: can you add error you are facing and what you have tried also add what is your souce

Comment: My source is Azure data lake storage table, and i cretaed linked & dataset service. please guide after step by step and i will try that

Answer (score 0):

To pull data from ADLS to Azure Data Explorer (Kusto) with selected columns from source table using azure data factory

- First allow ADF to access the cluster, to do this give permission to ADF **System assigned Managed Identity** and assign `AllDatabaseAdmin` role to it as below from **Cluster settings >> permission >> Add >> AllDatabaseAdmin**
  [image]
- First create a Sink dataset with Azure Data Explorer (Kusto) linked service
  select **authentication** as `System assigned managed identity`. The select your cluster and database.
  [image]
- After this add table where you want to copy data in the dataset.
  [image]
- Use Mapping to pull data from selected columns from source table click on import mapping and assign it properly to destination column.
  [image]

Comment: In the first Screen shot Type (App), from my side Type(User). How can I change that one.

Comment: which authentication method you want to use service principal user assigned managed identity or system assigned managed identity to authenticate with ADX